# -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal in DockerFile not Working

Tags: java, docker, jvm, dockerfile, flags

Using this in the DockerFile :

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+UseContainerSupport -XshowSettings:vm"
CMD exec java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal $JAVA_OPTS -cp app:app/lib/* my.package.MyApplication
```

The `-XshowSettings:vm` flag works fine, output is as follows :

```
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 1.52G
    Using VM: Eclipse OpenJ9 VM


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)
(... application starts running)
```

So as you can see, flags aren't printed out. Any ideas as to why?
Previously I used `ENTRYPOINT ...` in the DockerFile, not that it matters.

Full DockerFile :

```
FROM <harbor-link-to-base-image> AS exploded
COPY target/*.jar /app.jar
RUN mkdir -p /app && (cd /app; unzip -q ../*.jar -d .)
FROM <harbor-link-to-base-image>
# fontconfig.properties added explicitly to prevent NullPointer when loading Fonts, due to the file being missing in AdoptOpenJDK image
COPY --from=exploded /app/BOOT-INF/classes/fontconfig.properties $JAVA_HOME/lib
COPY --from=exploded /app/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=exploded /app/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=exploded /app/BOOT-INF/classes /app
RUN apk update
RUN apk add ttf-dejavu
# -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+UseContainerSupport -XshowSettings:vm"
CMD exec java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal $JAVA_OPTS -cp app:app/lib/* my.package.MyApplication
```

Comment: I guess you need to give more detail, with a simple program here, I can't reproduce your problem...

Comment: Hm, weird. I added the full `DockerFile`, I'm not sure what else could be shared that would give some more info. Not sure what could be interfering with the proper function of the flag.

Comment: What I used is `FROM openjdk:11`, not alpine or oracle jdk, not sure if it will have any difference... You may need to narrow down your issue with more trial I guess.

Comment: Ok, seems to be down to the base image I use, as it works fine if I use `openjdk:11`.

Comment: Right, you were using OpenJ9 VM, while `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` is specific to HotSpot JVM.

Comment: Ok strange, it's listed in [this reference](https://chriswhocodes.com/hotspot_options_jdk11.html) under OpenJ9. What's an alternative? I know of `-verbose:sizes` but I'd like all the flags.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse-openj9/openj9/issues/527

Comment: Yeah, I saw that thread but it's not equivalent.